# Command received by controller through serial interface but robot arm doesn't move

Tags: c#, serial-port, embedded, robotics

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace SerialPort
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        cmdClose.Enabled = false;
        foreach (String s in System.IO.Ports.SerialPort.GetPortNames()) 
        {
            txtPort.Items.Add(s);
        }
    }

    public System.IO.Ports.SerialPort sport;

    public void serialport_connect(String port, int baudrate , Parity parity, int databits, StopBits stopbits) 
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        String dtn = dt.ToShortTimeString();

        sport = new System.IO.Ports.SerialPort(
        port, baudrate, parity, databits, stopbits);
        try
        {
            sport.Open();
            cmdClose.Enabled = true;
            cmdConnect.Enabled = false;
            txtReceive.AppendText("[" + dtn + "] " + "Connected\n");
            sport.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sport_DataReceived);
        }
        catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString(), "Error"); }
    }

    private void sport_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)  
    {
        this.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
        {
            DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
            String dtn = dt.ToShortTimeString();       
            txtReceive.AppendText("[" + dtn + "] " + "Received: " + sport.ReadExisting() + "\n");
        }));
    }

    private void cmdConnect_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String port = txtPort.Text;
        int baudrate = Convert.ToInt32(cmbbaudrate.Text);
        Parity parity = (Parity)Enum.Parse(typeof(Parity), cmbparity.Text);
        int databits = Convert.ToInt32(cmbdatabits.Text);
        StopBits stopbits = (StopBits)Enum.Parse(typeof(StopBits), cmbstopbits.Text);

        serialport_connect(port, baudrate, parity, databits, stopbits);

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        String dtn = dt.ToShortTimeString();
        String data = txtDatatoSend.Text;
        sport.Write(data);
        txtReceive.AppendText("[" + dtn + "] " + "Sent: " + data + "\n");
    }

    private void cmdClose_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DateTime dt = DateTime.Now;
        String dtn = dt.ToShortTimeString();

        if (sport.IsOpen) 
        {
            sport.Close();
            cmdClose.Enabled = false;
            cmdConnect.Enabled = true;
            txtReceive.AppendText("[" + dtn + "] " + "Disconnected\n");
        }
    }
}
```

}

[image]

After I send command through the serial interface as shown in picture, my robot doesn't move at all. However, if I close visual studio and open software called Roboteq, my robot will move following the command I sent previously without even loading the port in Roboteq. Any idea why that is? I think the controller received my command for sure, but somehow it doesn't execute, and maybe opening Roboteq makes it execute. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Does your device require the command be terminated with a newline?

```
    sport.WriteLine(data);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.ports.serialport.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I tried what you suggested, but I think Write(data) and WriteLine(data) doesn't make any difference here. My controller require carriage return"\r"

Comment: More than that, no matter whether I add '\r' to terminate each command or not, the same thing happen again. I have no clue why that is..

Comment: Perhaps try slimming down your code a bit, and see if maybe your event handlers can be taken out if play for starters.  I was just skimming through an article about the "flakiness" of the System.IO.Ports.SerialPort implementation in the framework: http://www.sparxeng.com/blog/software/must-use-net-system-io-ports-serialport

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set the Motor Mode first ("^MMOD 6\r") and Then change the Serial Watchdog time-out to something like 5 seconds ("^RWD 5000\r") otherwise the G command will be immediately cancelled. Then you will be able to issue G commands

0: Open-loop
1: Closed-loop speed
2: Closed-loop position relative
3: Closed-loop count position
4: Closed-loop position tracking
5: Torque
6: Closed-loop speed position